# How to focus on custom ribbon tab when selecting row in the list grid. Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I wrote custom actions for entity. Combined and deployed it to the server, and linked from buttons in my custom tab.

Case "What is going on in SP2010":
I`m selecting list, then selecting row in the grid, and new contextual group "List tools" are showing above with two subtabs, where first one "Items" is focused on automatically.

Case "What i need":
Do the same, but at the last stage i want to focus on my custom tab, which will show my new actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyCustomTab.IsSelected = True
```

Comment: Definition of custom tab is in the Elements.xml, and i have no class